# Error: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a small app in which users input data. I can get the app running for one row, but am trying to generalize for any number of rows of source data. The source data is a two column csv with a description in the first column, and a dollar amount in the second column.

When doing this, I'm getting the error: `Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed`. I have read through all of the other questions regarding this error message, but can not figure out what the problem is. I presume the problem is the result of the reactive environment, but I haven't been able to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can make the problem clearer.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
thing <- data.frame("Description" = c("Description1","Description2","Description3"), FY2017.2018 = c(1500,2000,2500))

server <- function(input, output, i) {
  output$A[i] <- renderText({input$U[i]})
  output$B[i] <- renderText({input$V[i]})
  output$C[i] <- renderText({input$W[i]})
  output$D[i] <- renderText({input$X[i]})
  output$E[i] <- renderText({input$Y[i]})
  output$K[i] <- renderText({input$Z[i]})
  output$G[i] <- renderText({input$U1+input$U2+input$U3+input$U4+input$U5+input$U6})
}

v1 <- lapply(1:nrow(thing), function(i){
  fluidRow(column(1,thing$Description[i]),
           column(1, paste0("$",round(thing$FY2017.2018[i]))),
           column(1,sliderInput(inputId = paste0("U",i),label = NULL,value = 0,min=0,max = 100, step=5)),
           column(1,sliderInput(inputId = paste0("V",i),label = NULL,value = 0,min=0,max = 100, step=5)),
           column(1,sliderInput(inputId = paste0("W",i),label = NULL,value = 0,min=0,max = 100, step=5)),
           column(1,sliderInput(inputId = paste0("X",i),label = NULL,value = 0,min=0,max = 100, step=5)),
           column(1,sliderInput(inputId = paste0("Y",i),label = NULL,value = 0,min=0,max = 100, step=5)),
           column(1,sliderInput(inputId = paste0("Z",i),label = NULL,value = 0,min=0,max = 100, step=5))
           )
})

v2 <- lapply(1:nrow(thing),function(i){
  fluidRow(column(1, ""),
           column(1, ""),
           column(1, textOutput(paste0("A",i))),
           column(1, textOutput(paste0("B",i))),
           column(1, textOutput(paste0("C",i))),
           column(1, textOutput(paste0("D",i))),
           column(1, textOutput(paste0("E",i))),
           column(1, textOutput(paste0("K",i))),
           column(1, strong(textOutput(paste0("G",i))))
  )
})

v3 <- c(rbind(v1,v2))

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("simplex"),
  fluidRow(column(1,"Description"),
           column(1,"Current Expense"),
           column(1,"Cost Type 1"),
           column(1,"Cost Type 2"),
           column(1,"Cost Type 3"),
           column(1,"Cost Type 4"),
           column(1,"Cost Type 5"),
           column(1,"Cost Type 6"),
           column(1,strong("Total"))),
  v3      
)



shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Can you share some reproducible data?

Comment: Thanks for the advice - reproducible data included in code now.

Comment: When you run your `server()` function, what do you think is being passed to `i`? The server function does not get a third parameter. If you try printing that value out you'll see it doesn't exist.

Comment: I see your point MrFlick. I am trying to reference the same inputs/outputs from the ui section. I have tried running this function inside and outside of the server function to no avail. Do you have any further advice?